# Illustrator - batch insert filename in textpath script crashes Illustrator

Tags: javascript, adobe-illustrator, extendscript

First off: I am not a programmer. Just playing around with code and trying to get it to work for a specific task:

Here is a script I made for the purpose of inserting a text with the file name in over 600 pdf files. This is suppose to work on all files in a selected folder.

The problem: Illustrator crashes.

First test code, after a few edited files Illustrator crashed, so I tried to introduce a delay after each save in order to slow down the batch process.

$.setTimeout(function () {sourceDoc.close(SaveOptions.SAVECHANGES)}, 1000);

No idea what to do next. The code works if I delete this line: sourceDoc.close(SaveOptions.SAVECHANGES);

Here is the complete script:

```js
    var destFolder, sourceFolder, files, fileType, sourceDoc, layers, writeText, finLabel;  
      
    // Select the source folder.  
    sourceFolder = Folder.selectDialog( 'Select the folder with Illustrator files you want to convert to PNG', '~' );  
      
    // If a valid folder is selected  
    if ( sourceFolder != null )  
    {  
    files = new Array();  
    fileType = prompt( 'Select type of Illustrator files to you want to process. Eg: *.ai', '*.pdf' );  
      
    // Get all files matching the pattern  
    files = sourceFolder.getFiles( fileType );  
      
    if ( files.length > 0 )  
    for ( i = 0; i < files.length; i++ )  
    {  
        sourceDoc = app.open(files[i]); // returns the document object  
        layers = unlock();  
        writeText = getFilename();  
        finLabel = remText();  
        sourceDoc.close(SaveOptions.SAVECHANGES);   //if save command line is deleted the code works   WTF???  
        $.setTimeout(function () {sourceDoc.close(SaveOptions.SAVECHANGES)}, 1000); // still crashes using delay ...  
    }  
    //alert( 'Files are saved as PNG in ' + destFolder );  
      
    else  
    {  
    alert( 'No matching files found' );  
    }  
    }  
      
    function unlock()  
    {  
       //get the total number of layers in the active document  
    doc = app.activeDocument;  
    var totalLayers = doc.layers.length;  
      
    //looping on layers to create one artboard per layer  
    for ( var i = 0 ; i < totalLayers ; i++){  
          
        var currentLayer = doc.layers[i];  
          
        //We don't want to deal with hidden layers  
        if(currentLayer.visible == false) continue;  
          
        //Unlock the layer if needed  
        currentLayer.locked = false;  
      
    }  
        }  
      
    function getFilename()  
    {  
    // Write text  
    var pointTextRef = app.activeDocument.textFrames.add();  
    pointTextRef.contents = app.activeDocument.name + "\n" + "YBS";  
    pointTextRef.top = 0;  
    pointTextRef.left = 0;  
    app.activeDocument.textFrames[0].textRange.characterAttributes.textFont=app.textFonts[31];  
          
        }  
      
    function remText()  
    {  
    // This works for search and replace :))))))  
      
        var active_doc = app.activeDocument;    
            
        var search_string = /_Template.pdf/gi; // g for global search, remove i to make a case sensitive search    
        var replace_string = '';    
            
        var text_frames = active_doc.textFrames;    
            
        if (text_frames.length > 0)    
        {    
            for (var i = 0 ; i < text_frames.length; i++)    
              {    
                  var this_text_frame = text_frames[i];    
                   var new_string = this_text_frame.contents.replace(search_string, replace_string);    
                       
                   if (new_string != this_text_frame.contents)    
                       {    
                            this_text_frame.contents = new_string;    
                       }    
              }    
        }        
     }
```

Any ideas about what makes Illustrator crash?

Note: The application crashes after opening the first file.

Thanks for helping out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some things you should change and try:

1. There is no `$.setTimeout` in extendscript
2. Check if your file filter really works (`getFiles(FileType)`)
3. Your functions `unlock()`, `getFilename()` and `remText()` don't have return value so you don't need to pass their result into a variable
4. Try a subset of your pdf files, not all 600
5. add the `var` to your for loop `for(var i = 0; i < ...)`
6. Try to do your `for` loop from the end of the list of files `for (var i = files.length; i >= 0; i-- ){}`

Answer (score 2):

After deleting this line:

```
 $.setTimeout(function () {sourceDoc.close(SaveOptions.SAVECHANGES)}, 1000);
```

the code worked on 499 files in one batch :)

Turns out Illustrator crashed when trying to save a corrupt pdf.

@ fabiantheblind
Thank you for your help!